# Search contacts with attachments

Tags: search

I want to search for all contacts that have an attachment. How do I do this? I have looked under custom and advance searches. as well as searched all help documents for an answer.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out how to create a custom search using 'search builder' and it has an option to search for attachments in the drop down.

Issue resolved

Comment: That is good to hear :-). Still, do you not think it is worth a issue in the official CiviCRM issue tracker on http://issues.civicrm.org?

Comment: I think so because it should be a fairly simple task in my opinion. When i was doing my research, i saw many others asking for the same thing

Comment: Can you add the issue @Danielle?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible in the user interface strangely enough as far as I know :-( You can have a look in the tables if you are familiar with the database? The attachment location will be in table civicrm_file, and the link to the activity will be in table civicrm_enity_file. So getting the activities with attachments will be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM civicrm_entity_file WHERE entity_table='civicrm_activity'
```

Comment: I don't think I'm that familiar. haha  It seems like it would be a very simple thing to search for contacts with attachments. I would love to try your theory but can you give me a bit more direction?

Comment: If you are not that familiar it is going to be hard, and I also reckon you would not have direct access to your database? Have you ever done anything with phpmyadmin or tools like that?