# Where/how do you tag an attachment?

Tags: tags, documentation

Whilst looking at tags for other reasons, I noticed that you can create tags to be **Used for Attachments**.

I haven't found where this is covered in our documentation (certainly not in the section on tags that only refers to tagging contacts, activities or cases).

I can't include it in the documentation, because I haven't come across a situation where I can tag an attachment and I have no idea how it to do it.

If someone can explain when/where/how/why you tag attachments I can include it in the documentation for 4.7.

Answer (score 3):

JoAnne -

It seems to me that the most likely scenario for adding/tagging attachments is in the creation of activities - I tested adding a tag for attachments in the demo site, and when I created a meeting activity and opened up the attachment section, the tag field was there: http://screencast.com/t/fNc98uR6Uq

What puzzles me, however, is that there is no apparent way to search for attachments or activities/contacts with attachments (which is different from searching within the attachments, which would be an entirely different ballgame), other than Search Builder (which is somewhat opaque for a lot of the Civi users with whom I work).  I see [from this message](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3769/search-contacts-with-attachments) that others have asked the same question - until the attachment tags are searchable, the usability is a bit limited IMHO.

Hope this helps,
Lesley

Comment: Thanks Lesley, perhaps I will leave it out of the documentation until someone can explain to me what value is added by tagging attachments.