# Where to get PDF copies of CDN tax receipts?

Tags: cdn-tax-receipts

How can I find, search and access tax receipts that have been issued in a PDF format? Where and how do I do that??
I want to be able to attach a PDF copy of a TR to send to client.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to StackExchange!

In the Configuration for the CDN Tax Receipts Extension -> look for archive email address. That’s where carbon copies of any issued Tax Receipt will go.

If you want a copy becuase you want to re-issue a Tax Receipt then (when viewing the Contribution) hit the Tax Receipt button and then hit re-Issue.

Comment: @Anna You'll want to review the CRA rules about copies. If you're trying to provide a tax receipt to a client who was issued a receipt and has misplaced it or didn't receive it, there are fairly stringent reporting rules you'll want to know about.

Answer (score 0):

When a Tax invoice is downloaded or emailed Civi creates activity of type Download Invoice or Email Invoice respectively. So if you do a Find Activity on Download Invoice or Email Invoice and view the respective activity you will see file link in attachment section.

If you need a report to list those attachment than you can use guidance from this post [How do I search for Activity Attachments?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6502/how-do-i-search-for-activity-attachments)

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Anna is not asking for Invoices but about Tax Receipts created with the CDN TaxRexeipts extension